# Date range Split in C#

Tags: c#

I need to split the date in month wise for the given start date and end date in C#

Example User Input:

```
Start date : 5/20/2013
End date : 11/11/2013
```

I want to split the give date difference in month

Output:

```
StartDate    EndDate     NumberOfMonth
 5/20/2013   5/31/2013     .5
 6/1/2013    6/30/2013      1
 7/1/2013    7/31/2013      1
 8/1/2013    8/31/2013      1
 9/1/2013    9/30/2013      1
 10/1/2013   10/31/2013     1
 11/1/2013   11/11/2013    .5
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question with some code and detail?

Comment: Why is 5-20-2013 - 5-31-2013 defined as .5 months and not something more accurate?

Comment: Have you already tried to solve the problem on your own? If yes, post some code. If not, do so before you ask.

Answer (score 2):

I'll take a stab at this... You can use Linq to generate all the date ranges at once. It's not exactly the prettiest query, but it works.

```
DateTime start = ...
DateTime end = ...
var cal = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;

var range =
    from y in Enumerable.Range(start.Year, end.Year - start.Year + 1)
    let maxMonth = y < end.Year ? cal.GetMonthsInYear(y) : end.Month
    let minMonth = y > start.Year ? 1 : start.Month
    from m in Enumerable.Range(minMonth, maxMonth - minMonth + 1)
    let isStart = (y == start.Year && m == start.Month) 
    let isEnd = (y == end.Year && m == end.Month) 
    select new
    {
        StartDate = isStart ? start : new DateTime(y, m, 1),
        EndDate = isEnd ? end : new DateTime(y, m, cal.GetDaysInMonth(y, m)),
        NumberOfMonths = isStart || isEnd ? .5 : 1
    };
```

It iterates over the years from `start` to `end`, then iterates over the months in each year, with special handling on the edge cases (`isStart` and `isEnd`). This basic algorithm can be encapsulated in a function like this:

```
public class DateTimeRange
{
    Date StartDate { get; set; }
    Date EndDate { get; set; }
    float NumberOfMonths { get; set; }
}

public static IEnumerable<DateTimeRange> SplitByMonths(DateTime start, 
                                                       DateTime end, 
                                                       Calendar cal)
{
    return (
        from y in Enumerable.Range(start.Year, end.Year - start.Year + 1)
        let maxMonth = y < end.Year ? cal.GetMonthsInYear(y) : end.Month
        let minMonth = y > start.Year ? 1 : start.Month
        from m in Enumerable.Range(minMonth, maxMonth - minMonth + 1)
        let isStart = (y == start.Year && m == start.Month) 
        let isEnd = (y == end.Year && m == end.Month) 
        select new DateTimeRange
        {
            StartDate = isStart ? start : new DateTime(y, m, 1),
            EndDate = isEnd ? end : new DateTime(y, m, cal.GetDaysInMonth(y, m)),
            NumberOfMonths = isStart || isEnd ? .5 : 1
        });
}
```